# asterisk -vvvvvrx 'core show channels verbose'

Tags: asterisk

The output of the command `asterisk -vvvvvrx 'core show channels verbose'` shows total number of calls processed. That number is an indication of the calls processed since the service is running or last x hours or last x days?

Answer (score 1):

The total number of calls processed refers to the number of calls since the service is running. After a restart of asterisk this number is reset.